# is there a package manager console in xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin, nuget

I'm using xamarin studio (with nuget package management addin), and have some nuget-packages in my project.
There is "manage" and "restore nuget packages" in project context-menu, but is there a console too?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The addin for Xamarin Studio and MonoDevelop does not currently have a Package Manager Console built in. The main reason is the lack of support for PowerShell on non-Windows systems. There is [Pash](https://github.com/Pash-Project/Pash/), an open source, cross platform implementation of PowerShell, but that is currently missing some features before Xamarin Studio can get the full support compared with Visual Studio.

One of the features that the Package Manager console in Visual Studio is used for is to install a specific version of a NuGet package. With Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop 5.1 you can install a specific version of a NuGet package using the Add Packages dialog by running a version search `jquery version:*` where the package id must exactly match the package id on NuGet.org.

Note that there is a prototype Package Manager console available as a [third party addin](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions) for Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop 5.0 which was released recently. It is powered by Pash. However this console should be considered an alpha release. There are some PowerShell features missing from Pash which you may run into using this addin.

Comment: Meanwhile it is possible to have sort of PM console in Xamarin: Add-In manager, gallery, select Xamarin studio add ins (alpha channel), install NuGet PM extensions. Restart app. Find PM console under Pads