# xamarin studio, add nuget plugin

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin-studio

I've found a NuGet plugin I would like to install, but using Xamarin Studio on Mac I don't have Package Manager Console so i can't type the

```
Install-Package My.Wanted.Plugin -Version 1.0.0.0
```

According to [is there a package manager console in xamarin studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802905/is-there-a-package-manager-console-in-xamarin-studio) there is a workaround, but it didn't work for me.

So my questions is; is there another (probably longer and more complex) way to install NuGet plugins to Xamarin Studio?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: under Xamarin Studio --> Preferences --> Add In Manager, do you have NuGet installed?

Comment: Xamarin Studio -> Add In Manager -> NuGet Package Manager v 5.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Xamarin Studio 5.9 you can use version 0.6.1 of the [NuGet extensions addin](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions). Currently this is not currently available from the main [MonoDevelop addin repository](http://addins.monodevelop.com/) but it is available to download from [GitHub](https://github.com/mrward/temp-addin-upload).

Download the [mpack file](https://github.com/mrward/temp-addin-upload), then open the Add-in Manager and select Install from file. You may need to restart Xamarin Studio afterwards.

Comment: Will this be different from Xamarin Studio -> Add In Manager -> _Switch tab to_ Gallery -> _Change repository to_ Alpha -> IDE extensions -> Nuget Package Manager Extensions? Tried that one, and didn't work :(

Comment: @Pierre - Yes installing from file will be different. Currently from the gallery you can only get version 0.6 of the NuGet extensions addin.